# Instagram Referral Code not sent via Webhook (messaging_referral event)

Tags: instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

We've setup our app to receive webhook calls from Instagram when a user visits our conversation on Instagram Direct using ig.me link. We insert referral codes in ig.me links so we know where the user comes from (e.g. https://ig.me/m/testpagename?ref=website).

The problem we're facing is that IG is not calling the webhook for messaging_referral event, although we're subscribed to that event.

When we test the subscription on the dashboard, we do get the data, but in production, nothing comes in. Our app is live and the rest of it is working perfectly.

**Important note: the referral webhook is working perfectly for FB Messenger. It's only IG direct that is not working.
**

We raised this to Meta developer support, but no response!

Any thought please?

Comment: having the same issue, did you get it resolved in the end? This essentially renders ig.me links useless if the referral is not coming through in either the postback or messages as clearly is meant to as shown here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/instagram/features/ig-me-links

Comment: in my case it's the documentation, on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/instagram/features/ig-me-links

`"source": "SHORTLINKS"`

should read

`"source": "SHORTLINK"`

instead.